# JavaScript String concatenation bug on Firefox 3.6

Tags: javascript

This is my simple script:

```
<script>
    $("#adv").ready(function(){
        var x = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
            $("#adv").html('');
            x++;
            $('<img src="http://url/adv'+x+'.png?u=1&s=1&a='+x+'" />').appendTo('#adv');
            if(x == 2) {
                x = 0;
            }
        }, 20000);

    });
  </script>
```

Rotate image file every 20 seconds. Works perfectly but sometimes in server logs is see:

```
GET /adv%2527+x+%2527.png   403 Mozilla/5.0%20(Macintosh;%20U;%20PPC%20Mac%20OS%20X%2010.4;%20en-US;%20rv:1.9.2.4)%20Gecko/20100611%20 *Firefox/3.6.4*

GET /adv%2527+x+%2527.png   403 Mozilla/5.0%20(Windows;%20U;%20Windows%20NT%206.1;%20pl;%20rv:1.9.2.23)%20Gecko/20110920%20Firefox/3.6.23
```

So script concatenate script with quotas: **/adv%2527+x+%2527.png**
And this is only for Firefox 3.6.x

I also tested this on my Firefox 3.6 latest version, but this never happend for me.

anyone has idea how i should concatenate string to avoid this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the weird requests are truly coming from a browser?  It really looks to me more that a web robot or web crawler is walking your HTML, sees your script, sees the thing that looks like a URL, and then visits it.  Note that the URLs you're seeing aren't including the query portion, which is symptomatic of this.

Comment: Ah, this makes more sense than my explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should add the attribute `type=text/javascript` to the `<script>` tag. The browser is probably not executing the script and is instead trying to load the image with source `http://url/adv'+x+'.png?u=1&s=1&a='+x+'`, which gets url encoded to what you saw in the logs.

Comment: Javascript is the default script type anyway. Firefox 3.6 is not *that* bad

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is in the use of setTimeout.
The function isn't executed untill the setTimeout is executed by the browser, and I think that when the browser is unloading the page and the garbage collection collects all scripts but than runs the function inside the setTimeout and does not find a var x because it's already cleaned up and than just adds it as a string and injects the image.

My guess is that this not happens that much?

If this is the case you would solve it by clearing the setTimeout on page unload.

Hope it helps PM5544.

Comment: No, I disagree: garbage collection can't cause this, or else JavaScript is truly broken.  There's just too much behavior on the web that depends on the sound behavior of closures.

Comment: Well he point out this is only on one specific (and old) browser on a specific platform, so it can be a bug. and I did not say I think it was garbage collection but the combination of a twenty second timeout and the closing of the page.